# drawString in if statment not working in java

Tags: java

got some simple brick breaker game code here. When the player loses im tring to get 2 messages to appear. In the if statment, the rest of the code works as expected but the 2 strings dont appear. Any help would be appriciated thanks.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
        //background
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(1, 1, 692, 592);
        //drawing map
        map.draw((Graphics2D) g);
        //borders
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 3, 592);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 692, 3);
        g.fillRect(681, 0, 3, 592);
        //scores
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 25)); //this shows
        g.drawString(""+score, 500,30);
        //paddle
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(playerX, 550, 100, 8);
        //ball
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillOval(ballposX, ballposY, 20, 20);
        g.dispose();
        if(ballposY > 550) {
            play = false;
            ballXdir = 0;
            ballYdir = 0;
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 30));
            g.drawString("Game Over, your score is: ", 200, 200); // this dosent

            g.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
            g.drawString("Press Enter to Restart", 230, 250); //this dosent

        }

    }
```

Comment: You have disposed the `Graphics` object just before calling the if. Move it after the `if` body.

Comment: Actually you should NOT dispose of the Graphics object that is passed to a painting method. You should only dispose of a Graphics object that you create.